# how to read *redis.Client.TxPipeline.Exec() method's response in map[string]string

Tags: go, redis

I am using redis.v5. I want to read all redis keys value in one go, value of each key is hashMap i.e map[string]string. So I am using Redis transaction functionality of MULTI/EXEC. I have a function which does this, I am getting the response like this:

```
[hgetall x: map[VIN:POIUYTRUT4567ASWQ beaconID:1123VBG132 customerName:Amit displayLocation:waiting launge timestamp:2017-12-26T08:51:21.509Z] y: map[VIN:POIUYTRUT4567qweD beaconID:1123VBG13222 customerName:prameet displayLocation:waiting launge timestamp:2017-12-26T08:51:21.509Z]]
```

my function is this:

```
 func GetListOfValuesForKeys( keys []string,address, password string,db int) ([]map[string]string, error) {
    redisClient, err := redis.NewClient(loadRedisOptions(address, password, db))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    pipe := redisClient.TxPipeline()
    for _, val := range keys {
        pipe.HGetAll(val)
    }
    var data []map[string]string

    cmder, err := pipe.Exec()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    fmt.Printf("\n|**********res %++v**************|\n", cmder)

    return data, nil
}

func loadRedisOptions(address, password string, db int) *redis.Options 
{

return &redis.Options{
    Addr:     address,
    Password: password,
    DB:       db,
}
}
```

Now is there any inbuilt method in redis.v5 which can Unmarshal the pipe.Exec() method's response to map[string]string. pipe.Exec() method returns a slice of given below interface ([]Cmder):

```
    type Cmder interface {
    args() []interface{}
    arg(int) string
    name() string

    readReply(*pool.Conn) error
    setErr(error)

    readTimeout() *time.Duration

    Err() error
    fmt.Stringer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the definition of Exec:

`func (c *Pipeline) Exec() ([]Cmder, error)`

and `Cmder` implements

```
type Cmder interface {
    Name() string
    Args() []interface{}

    Err() error
    fmt.Stringer
    // contains filtered or unexported methods
}
```

and

`Cmder` implements `fmt.Stringer` which is defined as

```
type Stringer interface {
    String() string
}
```

where

> Stringer is implemented by any value that has a String method, which
>   defines the “native” format for that value. The String method is used
>   to print values passed as an operand to any format that accepts a
>   string or to an unformatted printer such as Print.

https://godoc.org/fmt#Stringer

**Therefore,**

You can access values by doing:

`Cmder.String()`

So what you're looking for is something like this:

```
cmdMap := map[string]string
cmder, err := pipe.Exec()
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
for cmd := range cmder {
    key := cmd.Name() // maybe use cmd.Args() to distinguish
    cmdMap[key] = cmd.String()
}
return cmdMap, nil
```

Let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: as i shared the cmder interface in my question it doesn't export  name and args . So i can not use cmd.Name() or cmd.Args() in my application

Comment: What output do you get when you do `cmd.Name()` and `cmd.Args()`?

Comment: i can't access name and args method only because in redis.v5 these are  not exported . please See the cmder interface struct in question above  .

Comment: i have also updated the GetListOfValuesForKeys()  functions return type it actually return []map[string]string , when i am setting data in redis for each key value is hashMap (map[string]string).

Comment: @negiYogi mate, `interface` is a behavioral contract, according to the interface you posted, it has `Name()` and `Args()` and all structs that implement that interface must have those functions by definition

Comment: that i understood, but as we are accessing cmder.name() and cmder.args out side the redis package, and name and args methods are public to redis package only , ,as you can see name and args are not exported , thats why i am unable to access these two methods in my application. Is there anything we can do ??

Comment: If you're using [this](https://godoc.org/github.com/go-redis/redis#Pipeline.Exec) client, then you should be able to access. Your interface starts with a lower case letter which means it's not publicly accessible

Comment: yeah cmder interface and methods it implements are accessible only to that package ,out that we can't access its methods , i tried the solution you have given , this  "cmd.Name()" is  undefined i can't access it . any Other way to do this  ??